# What is the difference between Apache NetUI and Struts?

Tags: struts, netui

What is the difference between JPF (Apache netUI) and Struts? When should I use JPF in web applications? What are the pros and cons about JPF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Apache Struts** is an open-source framework that provides support to [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) 
implementations of web-pages. Its goal is to separate these three parts of the project:  the **model** *(application logic that interacts with a database)* from the **view** *(HTML pages presented to the client)* and the **controller** *(instance that passes information between view and model)*.  It has a tag library
that eases the production of form-based applications with server pages.

**NetUI** is also a MVC framework that is part of [Beehive Project](http://beehive.apache.org/), which aims for the reduction of the necessary code on J2EE projects 
by using [JSR-175](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=175) [java annotations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_annotation). 
**NetUI was built atop Struts**, and it provides a *Page Flow Controller* class [that  separates navigational control from presentation](http://beehive.apache.org/docs/1.0/netui/overview.html)
of the web-project, keeping a clean JSP code and enabling the reuse of navigational/flow logic (also, it provides a set of JSP tags for rendering HTML/XHTML).

---

Now, regarding your other question about when to use JPF: Page flows control all of the major features of a web application: how users navigate from page to page, user requests, and access to the web application's back-end resources. You should use them when you need this kind of control for your application.

For example, with normal HTML pages, each page is linked directly to other pages.

```
page > page > page > page
```

When using page flows, pages and actions are interwoven, transparently.

```
page > action > page > action > page > action > page
```

Here is an image to illustrate this situation. The `.jsp` squares are static pages, while the other ones are JPF controllers.

[image: Example of JPF controllers use]

You can read more about all of this in the [apache beehive documentation](http://beehive.apache.org/), where I got the most of these information.